# Enforcing foreign constraints from parent form to child form using Sonata and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm having an issue wherein I have two entities I am adding data into (a Business entity and an Address entity), and one page where a business can be entered, along with an address.

A business can have many different sites, so can have many different addresses. Each Address entity has a Business property, which references the ID of the Business entity (This is reflected in the database via foreign keys and such).

The problem I'm having is that when entering the business and the address into the form, the submission fails because symfony is not inserting the newly created businesses ID into the newly created Address. In fact, as far as I am aware, according to the stack trace the Address query is being executed first.

Address Entity

```
namespace xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AddressOne", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $addressone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AddressTwo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $addresstwo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AddressThree", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $addressthree;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AddressFour", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $addressfour;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="City", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="County", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $county;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PostCode", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $postcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Latitude", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Longitude", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var \Business
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Business", inversedBy="address", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Business", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $business;

    /**
     * @var \Country
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Country", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $country;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set addressone
     *
     * @param string $addressone
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setAddressone($addressone)
    {
        $this->addressone = $addressone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get addressone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddressone()
    {
        return $this->addressone;
    }

    /**
     * Set addresstwo
     *
     * @param string $addresstwo
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setAddresstwo($addresstwo)
    {
        $this->addresstwo = $addresstwo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get addresstwo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddresstwo()
    {
        return $this->addresstwo;
    }

    /**
     * Set addressthree
     *
     * @param string $addressthree
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setAddressthree($addressthree)
    {
        $this->addressthree = $addressthree;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get addressthree
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddressthree()
    {
        return $this->addressthree;
    }

    /**
     * Set addressfour
     *
     * @param string $addressfour
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setAddressfour($addressfour)
    {
        $this->addressfour = $addressfour;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get addressfour
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddressfour()
    {
        return $this->addressfour;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set county
     *
     * @param string $county
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCounty($county)
    {
        $this->county = $county;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get county
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCounty()
    {
        return $this->county;
    }

    /**
     * Set postcode
     *
     * @param string $postcode
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setPostcode($postcode)
    {
        $this->postcode = $postcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postcode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPostcode()
    {
        return $this->postcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param string $latitude
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set longitude
     *
     * @param string $longitude
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set business
     *
     * @param \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Business $business
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setBusiness(\xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Business $business = null)
    {
        $this->business = $business;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get business
     *
     * @return \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Business 
     */
    public function getBusiness()
    {
        return $this->business;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Country $country
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCountry(\xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Country $country = null)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Country 
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * toString
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->addressone . " " . $this->postcode;
    }
}
```

Business Entity:

```
namespace xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Business
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Business")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Business
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="business", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * Get address
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $address
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     * 
     * @param \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setAddress(\xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address[] = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add address
     *
     * @param \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return Business
     */
    public function addAddress(\xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address[] = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Business
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * toString
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Remove address
     *
     * @param \xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address $address
     */
    public function removeAddress(\xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address->removeElement($address);
    }
}
```

ClinicsAdmin (This is the admin for the Business entity)

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

use xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Clinic;
use xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Address;

class ClinicsAdmin extends Admin
{

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('Name')
            ->add('Description')
            ->add('address')


            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                   'actions' => array(
                       'view' => array(),
                       'edit' => array()
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
                ->add('Name', 'text')
                ->add('Description', 'textarea')
                ->add('address', 'sonata_type_admin',
                    array(
            'by_reference' => true,     
                        'data_class' => null,
                        'label' => false,
                        'delete' => false



                    ),
                    array()
                );
    }
}
```

Address Admin

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

use xxx\BusinessFinderBundle\Entity\Country;

class AddressAdmin extends Admin
{

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('AddressOne')
            ->add('AddressTwo')
            ->add('AddressThree')
            ->add('AddressFour')
            ->add('City')
            ->add('County')
            ->add('Country')
            ->add('Description')
            ->add('Latitude')
            ->add('Longitude')



            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                   'actions' => array(
                       'view' => array(),
                       'edit' => array()
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->remove('create')
            ->remove('delete')
            ->remove('edit')
            ;

    }

    public function create($object)
    {
        var_dump($object);die();
    }
    public function preUpdate($obj)
    {
        var_dump($obj);die();
    }
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
            $formMapper
                    ->add('AddressOne', 'text')
                    ->add('AddressTwo', 'text', array('required' => false))
                    ->add('AddressThree', 'text', array('required' => false))
                    ->add('AddressFour', 'text', array('required' => false))
                    ->add('City', 'text')
                    ->add('County', 'text')
                    ->add('PostCode', 'text')
                    ->add('country', 'sonata_type_model')
                    ->add('Description', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
                    ->add('Latitude', 'text', array('required' => false))
                    ->add('Longitude', 'text', array('required' => false))

            /*
            ->add('Address', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'xxxBusinessFinderBundle:Address',
                    'required' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ),
                array (
                    'edit' => 'list'
                )
            )*/;
    }
}
```

These work in the sense that they insert into the database, but nothing gets inserted into the Business field of the Address entity, and once I set that to not null the query failed completely. What I am trying to figure out, is how to grab the ID from the newly created Business and plug it into the newly created Address entity.

Any and all help is appreciated :)